# PHP - Move_uploaded_file move file with Symbols unintelligible

Tags: php

I have a problem with `move_uploaded_file` function.

Problem is if I upload a arabic file its shows with Symbols unintelligible.

look at the picture

[image]

Comment: Showing some code would be good. Plus, if you can't find a solution to the problem, you can always rename your files to a numeric format. However, you have an encoding problem.

Comment: Try with http://www.php.net/setlocale

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this, but have you tried encoding the file name when you receive the string from the FILES array?

```
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there are libraries to fix this issue like [ar-php](https://github.com/tawfekov/ar-php)

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require("connect.php");
include 'Arabic.php';
$arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Transliteration');
if (isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'] as $count => $upload_file) {
        if (!empty($_FILES['image']['error'][$count])) {
            // Some error occured with the file in index $count
            // Put some error handling in here...
            return false; // or you could continue;
        }

        if (!empty($upload_file) && is_uploaded_file($upload_file)) {
            $charset = "AHfgG15Ds10MZD58N";
            $code = '';
            $length = 15;
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
                $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
                $tmp = substr($charset, $rand, 1);
                $code .= $tmp;
            }
            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT `code` FROM `files`  WHERE `code`='$code'") or die(mysql_error());
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

            while ($numrows != 0) {
                $code = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
                    $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
                    $tmp = substr($charset, $rand, 1);
                    $code .= $tmp;
                }
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT `code` FROM `files`  WHERE `code`='$code'");
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            }
            $types = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'rar', 'mp3', 'm4a', 'wmv', 'divx', 'mp4',
                           'flv', 'FLV', 'dvd', 'mkv', 'bmp', 'xml', 'doc', 'pdf', 'xls', 'psd', 'svg',
                           '3gp', 'ppt', 'txt', 'exe', 'mpeg', 'dvdrip');

            $names = pathinfo($_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$count]);
            if (in_array($names['extension'], $types)) {
                mkdir("upload/$code/");
                $name = trim($arabic->ar2en($_FILES["upload_file"]["name"][$count]));
                $type = $_FILES["upload_file"]["type"][$count];
                $size = $_FILES["upload_file"]["size"][$count];
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$count];
                if ($size < 600000000) {
                    $site_url = ('http://localhost');
                    $url = ("$site_url/download.php?file=$code");
                    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
                    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES ('Null','$name','$code','$type','$size','$url')");
                    $url = urlencode($name);
                    if ($upload = move_uploaded_file($upload_file, "upload/$code/" . $name)) {

                        if ($upload) {
                            ?>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h3>File name</h3></td>
                                    <td><h3>File Link</h3></td>
                                    <td><h3>File Type</h3></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo "$name"; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo "<a href='http://localhost/downoald.php?file=$code' target='_blanck'>File Link</a>"; ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><?php print_r($names['extension']); ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            No file selected
                        <?php
                        }

                    } else {
                        echo "A problem occurred while uploading your file(s), please try again.";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "This file(s) is up to 1GB<br>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Type of the file not allowed";
            }
        } else {
            echo "this error is fan";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "PHP 5 is not capable...", "Here's a library written in PHP 5 that does just that." Errr...?!

Comment: @deceze I meant without library, Im not so perfect in english bro

Comment: You do know that that library is just PHP code written in PHP, right? You could write that code yourself in your app to do the same thing, then you don't need the library... It's just that you need to be mindful of certain things to make it work, not that "PHP is not capable".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @meda
this my code please

Addition rode that were sent to me

```
    <?php
set_time_limit(0);
require("connect.php");
if (isset($_FILES['upload_file'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'] as $count=>$upload_file) {
            if (!empty($_FILES['image']['error'][$count])) {
            // Some error occured with the file in index $count
            // Put some error handling in here...
            return false; // or you could continue;
        }

        if (!empty($upload_file)&&is_uploaded_file($upload_file)) {
    $charset="AHfgG15Ds10MZD58N";
            $code='';
            $length=15;
            for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++) {
                $rand=rand()%strlen($charset);
                $tmp=substr($charset,$rand,1);
                $code.=$tmp;
            }
             mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
            $query=mysql_query("SELECT `code` FROM `files`  WHERE `code`='$code'") or die(mysql_error());
            $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

            while ($numrows!=0) {
                $code='';
                for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++) {
                    $rand=rand()%strlen($charset);
                    $tmp=substr($charset,$rand,1);
                    $code.=$tmp;
                }
                $query=mysql_query("SELECT `code` FROM `files`  WHERE `code`='$code'");
                $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
            }
            $types = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','zip','rar','mp3','m4a','wmv','divx','mp4','flv','FLV','dvd','mkv','bmp','xml','doc','pdf','xls','psd','svg','3gp','ppt','txt','exe','mpeg','dvdrip');
            $names = pathinfo($_FILES['upload_file']['name'][$count]);
            if (in_array($names['extension'],$types)) {
            mkdir("upload/$code/");
            $name=$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"][$count];
            $type=$_FILES["upload_file"]["type"][$count];
            $size=$_FILES["upload_file"]["size"][$count];
            $tmp_name=$_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$count];
            if ($size < 600000000)
            {
            $site_url=('http://localhost');
            $url= ("$site_url/download.php?file=$code");
            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
            $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES ('Null','$name','$code','$type','$size','$url')");
            $url=urlencode($name);
            if($upload = move_uploaded_file($upload_file ,"upload/$code/".$name))
            {

            if ($upload) { ?>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td><h3>File name</h3></td><td><h3>File Link</h3></td><td><h3>File Type</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo"$name"; ?></td><td> <?php echo"<a href='http://localhost/downoald.php?file=$code' target='_blanck'>File Link</a>"; ?></td><td><?php print_r ($names['extension']); ?></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            <?php } else { ?>
                No file selected
            <?php }

                        }else{
            echo "A problem occurred while uploading your file(s), please try again."; 
            }
            }else{
            echo "This file(s) is up to 1GB<br>";
            }
}else{
echo "Type of the file not allowed"; 
}
}else{
echo "this error is fan";
}
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: You should use answers button only to post answers, but what is wrong with this code

Comment: please edited my code .
my problem is files (arabic) save in database and move in folder with symbols-unintelligible

Comment: You need to implement the code I gave you, And you should tell me what went wrong if you face an issue

Comment: My problem is i set the code he is not work.
please do it and give me code complete.
Thank you !

Comment: and of course you dont tell me the error, I should know ?

Comment: Any error does not appear but the files are not uploaded